# Solving Trigonometric equation :$\frac{\sin{x}}{2 + \cos{x}} = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help solving  this equation for all values of $x$:

$$\frac{\sin{x}}{2} + {\cos{x}} = 1$$

(Note from editor: Rewritten as per OP's intentions. See OP's comment below to clarify which of two interpretations of the original post was intended.)

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{\sin(x)}{2+\cos(x)}=1$$ or $$\frac{\sin(x)}{2} +\cos(x)=1$$?

Comment: The second equation

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\frac{\sin{x}}{2 + \cos{x}} = 1 \iff \sin x = 2 + \cos x$$

Can you prove that equation is impossible?

It has to do with $|\cos x | \leq 1$ and $|\sin x| \leq 1$. You can't make the left hand side big enough and the right hand side small enough to make them meet.

Comment: @amWhy edited my answer. It was not just that but my cellphone's net went down

Comment: I would write $\sin x - \cos x = 2$. Then multiplying both sides by $1/\sqrt{2}$ gives $\sin\left( x - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) = \sqrt{2}$, which may be easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{\sin x}{2+\cos x}=1\\
\sin x = 2 + \cos x\\
\sin x - \cos x = 2$

This is impossible. Maximum of $\sin x$ is 1 and minimum of $\cos x$ is $-1$ but these are extreme cases and for same value of $x$ the above equation does not have any solution

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\sin(x)}{2+\cos(x)} = 1$
$\implies$ $\sin(x)-\cos(x) = 2$
$\implies$ $\sin(x) - \sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2}) = 2$
$\implies$ $\sin(x) + \sin(-x-\frac{\pi}{2}) = 2$
$\implies$ $2\sin(-\frac{\pi}{4})\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) = 2$ (because $(\sin(A) + \sin(B) = (2\sin(\frac{A+B}{2})\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})$)
$\implies$ $\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) = -\sqrt{2}$
but $-1 < \cos(x+\frac{\pi}4) < 1$ so no solutions exist for $x$.

**EDIT:** Actual equation according to OP in comment below is $\frac{\sin(x)}{2} + \cos(x) = 1$:
$\frac{\sin(x)}{2} + \cos(x) = 1$
$\implies$$\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\sin(x+\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}))=1$
this is by $A\sin(x)+B\cos(x) = \sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(x+\phi)$, where $\phi$ is the angle between the line connecting $(A,B)$ to the origin and the $x$-axis. $x$ is now easily solved for.

Comment: I am not writing the equation correctly.  Sorry.

Comment: sin of x divide by 2 minus cos = 1

Comment: Okay user391127, edited.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint 1

As @RSerrao points out, the problem is reducible to $\sin(x)=2+\cos(x)$ so we can find all the points where the left-hand-side reaches a maximum and then find all the points where the right-hand-side reaches a minimum. But are these the same points?

#### Hint 2

If you've learnt some foundational skills in calculus, you could consider the problem as the roots of $f(x)=2+\cos(x)-\sin(x)$. If $f'(x)=\cos(x)-\sin(x)$, where does $f'(x)=0$ and where are the minimums of the function?